# Pandas - Interpolation between Columns

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I've got a question and hope you can help me. Suppose a Pandas Dataframe who looks something like this:

[image]

I would like to do a linear interpolation to fill the missing nan values. While I was searching I only found examples when the values in the same column had to be interpolated, nothing cross column.
Is there a way to do an interpolation between the left and right of the nan values?

Kind regards

PS: a code snipped:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'A':[2,4,6,8,4],
        'B':[0,0,0,0,0],
        'C':[4,10,4,5,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B','C'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`interpolate` can be used on horizontal axis, but only NaN values are considered

```
df['B'] = np.NaN
df = df.fillna(df.interpolate, axis=1)
```

It gives:

```
   A    B   C
0  2  3.0   4
1  4  7.0  10
2  6  5.0   4
3  8  6.5   5
4  4  2.5   1
```

Comment: Hi @serge-ballesta. Thanks for the nice explanation. If the value in the 1st column is `nan`, what'd be the best way to impute here?

Comment: @Roy: You could try to `bfill` the first column before calling `interpolate`: `df.iloc[:,0] = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]`

Answer (score 1):

```
df.interpolate(axis=1)
```

will interpolate along columns.

Comment: How would you implement this: df['B'].interpolate(method='linear', axis=1) gives this error: ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>.  And just using your code snipped for my problem won't actually do aynthing. I don't need to interpolate ALONG columns, I need to do it ACROSS columns, namely between the adjacent columns.

Comment: That's because column B above is filled with zeros. It'll fill NaNs with interpolated values. Try filling B with NaNs to see the effect