# How to linearly interpolate a new column from existing columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, interpolation

I am trying to use the values in two available columns for linearly interpolating a new column. I am using `np.interp`, but it gives an error about `fp`. Can anyone suggest a way using `pandas` or `numpy` for such a linear interpolation?

```
X1      X2
34.5    36.3
12.4    11.3
16.5    15.9
8.5      8.1
56.6    55.6


df['intreped_X'] = pd.Series(dtype='float') #adding a new column with NaN
df['intreped_X'] = np.interp(df['X1'].values,
                           df['X2'].values)
```

Error: `TypeError: _interp_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp'`.

Update:
I also tested the following script from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61251268/pandas-interpolation-between-columns), but does not produce new values in the new column and just adds the `"bound method NDFrame.interpolate ..."` in each row.

```
df['intreped_X'] = np.NaN
df = df.fillna(df.interpolate, axis=1)
print(df)

     X1                   intreped_X                     X2
0   34.5    <bound method NDFrame.interpolate of A ...  36.3
1   12.4    <bound method NDFrame.interpolate of A ...  11.3
2   16.5    <bound method NDFrame.interpolate of A ...  15.9
3   8.5     <bound method NDFrame.interpolate of A ...  8.1
4   56.6    <bound method NDFrame.interpolate of A ...  55.6
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - Interpolation between Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61251268/pandas-interpolation-between-columns)

Comment: What is your expected `interpred_X` column?

Comment: @Shaido please see the update in the question

Comment: @ OnY I am not sure about the expected values. Is there any way to only use the two existing columns? or it is not possible at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new column between the two existing ones filled with `NaN` values and then use [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) with `axis=1`:

```
df.insert(1, 'intreped_X', np.nan)
df.interpolate(axis=1)
```

Result:

```
      X1  intreped_X    X2
0   34.5       35.40  36.3
1   12.4       11.85  11.3
2   16.5       16.20  15.9
3   8.5         8.30   8.1
4   56.6       56.10  55.6
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Does this interpolation acts as calculating a mean?, The second column is like a mean of first and third columns.

Comment: @rayan: Yes, when using a linear interpolation between two values it would be the same as the mean of the two. You can see some more methods/examples in the documentation link.